# How to remove efficiently some elements from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, memory-leaks, dictionary-comprehension

I want to filter out some elements from a Python dictionary. Which way is more preferable? My dictionary is quite big...

Below is however an example code with a smaller data set:

```
d = {0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 4, 3: 6, 4: 8, 5: 10}
```

**1st**

```
d = {i:v for i, v in d.items() if i%2 == 0}
```

**2nd**

```
list_to_del = []
for i in d.keys():
    if i%2 == 0:
        list_to_del.append(d)
for i in list_to_del:
    del d[i]
list_to_del.clear()
```

Is there any risk of memory leak in the first case?

Comment: The first method is definitely cleaner to read, and memory leaks aren't a concern here.  Have you timed the two approaches to see if there's any notable performance difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, your first one looks exactly how I would do it. However, if you do need to just iterate over the entries and filter, try just leaving it in iterator form.

```
entries = filter(lambda x: x[1] % 2 == 0, d.items())
```

Answer (score 0):

The first one is faster. The `.append()` is quite slow, so your first for-loop in the second answer will need longer than itterating over elements